# If two forms in a view, how to pass both sets of params when one is submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view with two forms.  A main form to create a new contact and another form to add a new folder (for organization).

Is it possible to get params for both forms to be set when one of the forms is submitted?  Say, if a new folder is created I'd like to return to the view with any filled out contact  information still there (or the other way around if the main form has errors).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a basic constraint of HTTP that a form submission only includes the values for the submitted form (which is, of course, a feature, not a bug).

Options to actually deal with your need:

- If the two forms go to the same place, you could of course simply make them one big form; they can look like two forms visually without being two forms within the page
- You could use javascript to populate one form with hidden fields representing the values in the other form.  These could be updated either whenever the values change, or just before the actual submission takes place
- Or (and this is what you should do, in my opinion) you could make both forms submit via AJAX rather then submitting the full page.  That way, the form that hasn't been submitted won't change anyway, and there won't be any need to restore the values.

Comment: Rails makes it easy; look at view methods such as `remote_form_for`.